# Check the number of times a word or a phrase was tweeted

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I have a general question regarding twitter APIs in python - is there a way to get the total number of times a particular word, or phrase were tweeted?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for downgrading and not explaining why. It seems that you've really put a great effort into it.

Comment: Someone probably down-voted because it doesn't fit SO rules for how to write a good question. Basically, the expectation is that you should try to write the code and explain what's wrong and what you expected. You might want to check the SO help docs to see what means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get that for the life of Twitter. However, you might be able to the search API to get an idea of how many times over the last 2 weeks, which is the approximate max amount of time the search API goes into the past:

```
auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
search_results = api.search(q="<your word>")
```

Then count the number of tweets you get back for an approximation.

For more info, look at the [Tweepy Search API](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.8.0/api.html#help-methods). Also, look at [Tweepy Cursors](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/cursor_tutorial.html) for getting more than the default count of tweets.

Comment: Thank You so much for your help! I highly appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help - it's also considered good form to mark answers that fix a problem as solved and up vote a well-written question or answer.